# update named environment variables in airflow via command line

Tags: json, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an existing variable on airflow called
BLUE_APPLE.

I'm currently logged into the airflow web server.

```
airflow variables --get BLUE_APPLE
```

displays

```
  {
    "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
    "name": "main_window",
    "weedth": 500,
    "height ": 500
}
```

How do I update this BLUE_APPLE from the command line to reflect (weedth->width, and removing whitespace beside height):

```
  {
    "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
    "name": "main_window",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 500
}
```

I looked at
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref#variables

```
airflow variables [-h] [-s KEY VAL] [-g KEY] [-j] [-d VAL] [-i FILEPATH]
              [-e FILEPATH] [-x KEY]
```

But there are no examples on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `-s` or `-i` option.

with `-s KEY VAL` (Set variable for key)

```
airflow variables -s BLUE_APPLE "{ \"title\": \"Sample Konfabulator Widget\", \"name\": \"main_window\", \"width\": 500, \"height\": 500 }"
```

with `-i FILEPATH` (Import JSON file)

```
airflow variables -i /path/to/my/variables.json
```

and the variables.json should have

```
{
    "BLUE_APPLE": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    }
}
```

In both options, you need to pass the whole object, since you cannot update a child key within the object.

Comment: For the latest version of airflow -i now seems to be just import